# Delay the subsequent lines

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to delay executing the subsequent lines something like:

```
//block of code

if (//some condition) {
   delay(1000)
}

//block of code
```

How can I do that? I tried using `while` loop something like:

```
var del = 0
setTimeOut(function(){del = 1}, 1000)
while (del === 0) {console.log("waiting for 1 second");}
```

But it caused the browser to crash.
So is there a statement or a method or function that can do that in a clean way?

**Note**: I don't want to use a `setTimeOut` to call a function

Or is there something like delay in animations like:

```
$("#editor img").on("mouseenter",slideInTag)
                .delay(1000)
                .on("mouseenter",slideOutTag);
```

Comment: No, there is not. You *have* to use `setTimeout` with a callback function.

Comment: Why you don't want to use `setTimeout`?

Comment: `Or is there something like delay in animations like`: Yes, you can transform `setTimeout` into a Promise, but that would just be syntactical sugar

Comment: `jQuery` uses `setTimeout` under the hoods: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/queue/delay.js#L14-L17 (investigate more on [jQuery.queue](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/queue.js "queue.js")).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Based on the comments of @Rahul Tripathi answer.*

Set `this` into a variable and use the variable instead of `this`.

```
$(selector).on("mouseenter", function(){
    var x = this;
    setTimeOut(function () {slideOutTag(x)}, 1000);
})
```

Comment: Yes thats the way to proceed! +1

Answer (score 1):

Short answer if you dont want to use settimeout then there is **NO** way to do that.

Comment: @RanaMallah:- The answer still stands to NO(*as RGraham has said you can use promise but that would lead to syntactic sugar*). BTW why you dont want to use setTimeOut?

Comment: because with setTimeOut you can't pass a parameter like (this)

Comment: @RanaMallah:- Can you elaborate more on `because then you can't pass a parameter`?

Comment: @RanaMallah Your argument is false. It is completely possible to pass an argument.

Comment: I want to call a function on mouseenter and inside this function I want to call 'this'. If i used setTimeOut 'this' is going to be the window

Comment: @RanaMallah So, set "this" into a variable and use the variable instead of "this".

Comment: Why dont you use function () {}.bind(this)?

Comment: How can you do that in `$(selector).on("mouseenter", function(){setTimeOut(slideOutTag, 1000)})`

Comment: @RanaMallah: try like this: `$(selector).on("mouseenter", function(){
    var x = this;
    setTimeOut(function () {slideOutTag(x)}, 1000);
})`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to block the current thread in javascript.

Comment: You are not delaying the thread/execution with what you've updated, you are just delaying an animation. Is not the same. As I stated in my answer, there is NO way to block the current thread in javascript.

Comment: I meant can I use delay with events like in animations?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use setTimeOut. So in your case it would be:

```
$("#editor img").on("mouseenter", function(){ 
  setTimeout(function(){slideOutTag()},1000)
}
```

And you'd have to define a `slideOutTag` function which will be called after "mouseenter" and one second.

If you want to have "time-breaks" in between, you need to add a function each time, as I showed here.

Comment: `You need to use setTimeOut` OP has clearly mentioned that he doesnt want to use setTimeOut

Comment: Ah, that wasn't there in the first version. Well, then good luck.